# JVM Exited. Error Code 13 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS/eclipse-jee-2020-12-R-linux-gtk-x86_64

Tags: java, eclipse

I understand that this question may have been asked before and have gone through them but I am still stuck on the same `JVM Exited. Error Code 13` while trying to launch
eclipse on Ubuntu by directly specifying path to Java -

```
./eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

**Java**

[image]

**Eclispe Error**

[image]

**Error Log:**

```
!SESSION Tue Jun 15 23:00:33 IST 2021 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2021-06-15 23:00:33.052
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find framework under /home/sandeep/Documents/plugins
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
```

I have tried multiple Java distributions(8/11/15) - giving same Exit Code 13. I am not sure what exactly is missing here.

Comment: You need a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: `java -version` gives me `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)`.

Comment: Looks like it might be [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568604) Eclipse bug - the `#` characters in the path are causing a problem. Try running from a path which does not contain any `#` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by Eclipse bug [568604](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568604).

`#` characters in the install path are confusing Eclipse and causing it to look in the wrong place.

So install Eclipse in a location without `#` in the path.